# Finally runs in try/except/finally code block without waiting for complete output of try in Python

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I have a code block, something like :

```
file_ctr = 4
try:
    if (file_ctr!=5):
        raise ValueError('The number of files is different than expected.')
    print("I made it")
    print("I made it")
    print("Model scoring will start now")
    # Model scoring code
except Exception as e:
    print("Feature set not up-to-date.")
    print(e)
finally:
    print("Shutting notebook")
    # sagemaker_client.stop_notebook_instance(NotebookInstanceName=get_notebook_name())
```

My issue is the code in try block if it doesn't throw an exception is supposed to take about 2 hours for the model to score. However, *sometimes*, the code doesn't wait for the model scoring to get completed, and proceeds to finally and tries to shut the notebook.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Don't catch a general `Exception`, catch the only one(s) you expect. Most probably it just throws some error. Does it print anything before `"Shutting notebook"`?

Comment: Everything causing the behavior you claim has been replaced with `# Model scoring code`. Whatever explanation you are looking for would be there.

Comment: Actually, you should probably try catching `BaseException` not `Exception`. A few exceptions, such as those intended to simply cause your program to terminate, are instances of `BaseException` not `Exception`. If you want to catch every exception to see why your script is terminating, that's what you should be catching.

Comment: On the hand, I don't know  how you are running it. But you really shouldn't need to catch errors yourself just to see error output.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic, your intermediate step fails, and you get your `finally` block executed. Try tracing the code and seeing what cases `try` block fails. If the calls in `try`block are **sequential**, they will be awaited; otherwise you have to enforce awaiting them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set `file_ctr = 4`, your `try` block should *always* throw the `ValueError` (unless you reassign `file_ctr` to 5 somewhere else), because `4 != 5` is always `True`.

The `except` block catches the `ValueError` (which is subclass of `Exception`) and then `finally` performs a cleanup.

Thus, when I run your code, I get the following print-out:

```
Feature set not up-to-date.
The number of files is different than expected.
Shutting notebook
```

i.e.,
(1) `print` under `except Exception...`,
(2) contents of `Exception` (namely, `ValueError`), and
(3) `print` in the `finally` block.

In other words, in the code you provided `Model scoring code` should *never* run.